# 'I don't believe that is who betrayed me.' Is this sentence mistaken?

Tags: grammar

I see the sentence in the book:**I don't believe that is who betrayed me.**.

I can not understand its meaning and I think it is wrong. Am I right?

Comment: It's not incorrect.

Comment: Nor would it be incorrect if it included a "relativizer" ***that*** AS WELL AS a "pronominal" one: *I don't believe **that that** is who betrayed me*. Note that in speech those two highlighted terms would normally be treated very differently. The initial relativizer would only have an unstressed neutral vowel / schwa, whereas the pronoun would be fully articulated and given stress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction is idiomatic and commonplace. It is a short form of saying:

> I don't believe that (person) is (the individual) who betrayed me.

In this instance **that** is being used as a pronoun to refer to the person concerned.

You could insert a second **that** by saying:

> I don't believe that (conjunction) that (pronoun) is (the individual) who betrayed me.
> But this is unnecessary. In both spoken and written English, the first **that** is commonly omitted.

You will frequently come across constructions such as:

> I don't believe that's who did it.
> I don't believe that's the man responsible.
> I don't believe that's who you are.